# Changing ylabels on matrix plot

Tags: r

I would like to plot wind speed with height over time. I have been able to do this using a matrix plot however now that I am attempting to make my yaxis labels be more standardized (0,100,200,300 meters...etc) but do not know how as currently the indexes for yaxis (0:200) line up with the actual altitudes.

Any ideas to alter this code or another plot type are welcome.

data can be downloaded here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSdYIBHyvv0ue1YMqXVUqVSeUyYbZH4fl-XhXe_tVa42iJsTGejeGX1re06-jL-kYiuIJCUohdvEL7k/pub?output=csv

EDIT: explanation of data file:

dimensions of data are 715 col and 200 rows not including header. Header shows times while the altitude vector (length 200) corresponds to the rows.

current output:
[image]

Reviewed the code to ensure it works. Apologies for the repost:

code:

```
wind_speeds <- data

altitudes <- c(1,29,58,87,116,145,174,203,232,261,290,319,348,377,406,435,464,493,522,551,580,609,638,667,696,725,
               754,783,812,841,870,899,928,957,986,1015,1044,1073,1102,1131,1160,1189,1218,1247,1276,1305,1333,1362,
               1391,1420,1449,1478,1507,1536,1565,1594,1623,1652,1681,1710,1739,1768,1797,1826,1855,1884,1913,1942,
               1971,2000,2029,2058,2087,2116,2145,2174,2203,2232,2261,2290,2319,2348,2377,2406,2435,2464,2493,2522,
               2551,2580,2609,2637,2666,2695,2724,2753,2782,2811,2840,2869,2898,2927,2956,2985,3014,3043,3072,3101,
               3130,3159,3188,3217,3246,3275,3304,3333,3362,3391,3420,3449,3478,3507,3536,3565,3594,3623,3652,3681,
               3710,3739,3768,3797,3826,3855,3884,3913,3941,3970,3999,4028,4057,4086,4115,4144,4173,4202,4231,4260,
               4289,4318,4347,4376,4405,4434,4463,4492,4521,4550,4579,4608,4637,4666,4695,4724,4753,4782,4811,4840,
               4869,4898,4927,4956,4985,5014,5043,5072,5101,5130,5159,5188,5217,5245,5274,5303,5332,5361,5390,5419,
               5448,5477,5506,5535,5564,5593,5622,5651,5680,5709,5738,5767)


unique_hrs <- c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06" ,"07", "08", "09" ,"10", "11", "12", "13", "14" ,"15" ,"16", "17" ,"18", "19", "20" ,"21" ,"22", "23")

unique_hrs_index <- c(16, 46, 76, 106, 135, 165, 195, 225, 255, 285, 314, 344, 374, 404, 433, 463, 493, 523, 553, 583, 612, 642, 672)

min <- 0
max <- 12


library(viridis)
ColorRamp <- viridis(n = (max*2))
ColorLevels <- seq(min, max, length=length(ColorRamp))

# Set layout.  We are going to include a colorbar next to plot.
layout(matrix(data=c(1,2), nrow=1, ncol=2), widths=c(4,1),
       heights=c(1,1))

#plotting margins.  These seem to work well for me.
par(mar = c(4,5,4,2), font = 2)

# Plot it up!
image(1:ncol(wind_speeds), 1:nrow(wind_speeds), t(wind_speeds),
      col=ColorRamp, xlab="Time (UTC)", ylab="Altitude (m)",
      axes=FALSE, zlim=c(min,max), ylim = c(0,55), 
      main= NA)

#annotate the plot
box()
axis(side = 1, at=unique_hrs_index, labels=unique_hrs,
     cex.axis=1.0)
axis(side = 2, at=seq(1,length(altitudes),1), labels=round(altitudes), las= 1,
     cex.axis=1)

# Add colorbar to second plot region
par(mar = c(3,4,4,2))
image(1, ColorLevels,
      matrix(data=ColorLevels, ncol=length(ColorLevels),nrow=1),
      col=ColorRamp,xlab="",ylab="Wind Speed m/s",xaxt="n", las = 1)
```

Comment: Can you explain what are the dimension of the data `wind_speed` ? Your google documents contains more data than `altitude`. Can you provide a small example of wind_speed dataset in order we understand how you are plotting it ?

Comment: Your `axis(2, ...)` command is plotting the actual the altitude values. Try something like `axis(side=2, at=seq(0,1600, by=200), labels=seq(0, 1600, by=200), las-1, cex.axis=1)`. This assumes the y-axis scale is altitude. If it is just consecutive values, you need to interpolate.

Comment: @dc37 hopefully my edit clarifies.

Comment: @dcarlson I tried this and it shows no ylabels now.

Comment: `par("usr")` shows 0.5, 715.5,   0.0,  55.0 so the user coordinates span 715 on the horizontal (x) axis but only 55 on the vertical (y) axis. Are the 200 altitude values truncated? The values on your original plot only go to 1565, not the maximum altitude of 5767.

Comment: @dcarlson yes so I did this as wind speeds past index 55 that are mostly NA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plotted altitude values on the y-axis are only a small part of the range of the values (1565 versus 5767). This proposed solution assumes the plot is correct and you just want sensible values over that range. Replace your `axis(side=2, ... )` command with the following:

```
y = seq(1,length(altitudes),1)    
alt.lm <- lm(y~altitudes)
ylbl <- seq(0, 1500, by=250)
yval <- predict(alt.lm, data.frame(altitudes=ylbl))
axis(side = 2, yval, ylbl, las=1, cex.axis=1)
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thank you, I am getting an error that says `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object y not found`  what is `y` here? Just a sequence from 1:200?

Comment: EDIT: yes setting  `y = seq(1,length(altitudes),1)` works. Thank you!